# Why am I getting an infinite loop in this script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a program that asks for the user to add a directory, contact name and a contact number.

If the contact name already exists in the directory specified by the user then the file name becomes **contact(1).txt**. If that also exists, then the new file created becomes **contact(2).txt**, etc.

When I try to execute the following code, I get an infinite loop, I have tried looking for bugs, but couldn't find any.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=
if(($# == 0))
then
  echo -n "Please enter directory path:"
  read directory 
  cd $directory


  echo -n "Please enter contact name:"
  read name

  echo -n "Please enter contact number:"
  read number

else
  directory=$1
  cd ${directory}

  name=$2
  number=$3
fi

if [ -e $name.contact ];

then
  exists=1
  count=1

  while [ $exists==1 ];
  do
    name=$name\($count\)
    count=$(($count+1))
    if [ ! -f $name.contact ];
    then
      exists=0
      echo $exists
    fi

  done

  echo $number > $name.contact

else

  echo $number > $name.contact

fi
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `while [ $exists==1 ];` should be `while [ $exists -eq 1 ];`.

Comment: Also, if this is Bash, you probably really want to use double-brackets (`[[` and `]]`) instead. Check out http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces here:

```
if [ "$exists" = 1 ]; then
```

Notice also the use of double quotes, and the single equals sign.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help :) The code works. But I have one problem, I can't create more than contact(1).txt in my directory. I don't know what the problem is, do you know what the problem is ?

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question in accordance with the site's guidelines. Anyway, there can only ever be one file in a single directory with that specific name.

Comment: And if this answer solved your immediate problem, marking it as accepted would be a nice gesture. Thanks!